# Winston - Display error stack trace object and normal formatted message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, winston

I have the below logger file-

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, prettyPrint, timestamp, printf, simple } = format;

// set default log level.
const logLevel = 'info';

const errorStackFormat = format((info) => {
  if (info instanceof Error) {
    return Object.assign({}, info, {
      stack: info.stack,
      message: info.message
    });
  }
  return info;
});

var logger = createLogger({
  level: logLevel,
  levels: {
    error: 0,
    warn: 1,
    info: 2,
    http: 3,
    verbose: 4,
    debug: 5,
    silly: 6
  },
  format: combine(
    prettyPrint(),
    timestamp({
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss A'
    }),
    errorStackFormat(),
    simple(),
    printf((info) => {
      return `${info.timestamp} - ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
    })
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

If I pass a normal message like this - `logger.info('Normal message')`, I get the output as `14-10-2020 12:58:01 AM - info: Normal message`, but if I try to pass an error object like this - logger.info(new Error('error')), I get the output as `14-10-2020 01:02:23 AM - info: error`. If I put a console log in the `errorStackFormat` method, I am getting the proper `stack trace object` there in that method, then why it isn't getting consoled?
If I move the `simple()` call below `printf`, then I get the stack trace properly. What change should I make to get normal formatted messages via `printf` in case of non-error and stack trace messages in case of error?